# CSS: using .contentHere vs div.contentHere

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have seen both examples quite a bit.

Let's say you have

`<div class="contentHere"></div>`

So in css are both methods correct like this?

Method 1: `.contentHere { }`

Method 2: `div.contentHere { }`

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, either way is fine. `div.contentHere` is just more specific and only applies to `<div>` elements with that class whereas `.contentHere` is type-agnostic.

Note that if you specify *both*, styles declared in `div.contentHere` will override those in `.contentHere` in [the cascade](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/cascade), due to the former having more specificity.

Answer (score 2):

.contentHere will apply to ANY element with class="contentHere" be it a span, div, p, td, etc.

div.contentHere will only apply to div elements with class="contentHere".

Answer (score 0):

Method one will apply to any element which has the class "contentHere".

Method two will only apply to `<div>` elements which have the class "contentHere".